# PHP send email foreach user

Tags: php, mysql, sql, email, foreach

For this page i need to get managers email from users and send email to each managers email where the endofmonthdate = 22/09/2016

http://pastebin.com/7PD2MyuC

Thank you in advance!!

Comment: column datatype for `endofmonthform` ???? DATE or DATETIME or VARCHAR?

Comment: @devpro Varchar

Comment: run your query in php my admin, you will get the idea. `SELECT * FROM `clients` WHERE endofmonthform="22/09/2016"`

Comment: I have done this. Thats not the issue. The issue is selecting each individual managers email and send the email to each manager rather than just the one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code was missing some curly brackets ( {} ):

```
include ("../dbconnect.php");

$sql='SELECT c.endofmonthform, c.startofmonthform, c.email, c.id, c.formlevel, c.mastersite, c.opmanager, u.userEmail FROM `clients` as c LEFT JOIN `users` as u on c.opmanager = u.userName WHERE endofmonthform="22/09/2016"'; //TODAYS DATE BACK HERE!

$result=mysql_query($sql); 

 while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){  

    $enddate = $row['endofmonthform']; // End

    $startdate = $row['startofmonthform']; // Start

    $email = $row['email']; //Email to send email to

    $id = $row['id'];

    $formlevel = $row['formlevel']; //To update and check formlevel

    $sitegroupname = $row['mastersite'];

    $manager = $row['opmanager'];

    $opemail = $row['userEmail'];

    /* If end date is today and form level is still ZERO then send email to op manager */
    $mail = new EMail;

    $mail->Username = 'Sender email';    
    $mail->Password = 'mypwd';
    $mail->SetFrom("senderemail@example.com","companyname");  
    $mail->ContentType = "text/html";
    $mail->Subject = "Client feedback incomplete NEW LAYOUT";

    //Enter the email address you wish to send TO (Name is an optional friendly name):
    $mail->AddTo($opemail,$manager);


    $mail->Message = "<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC  -//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN   http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd >
    <html xmlns=http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv=Content-Type  content=text/html; charset=utf-8 />
    <title></title>
    <style type=text/css >
    body {margin: 0; padding: 0; min-width: 100%!important;}
    .content {width: 100%; max-width: 600px;}  
    </style>
    </head>
    <body yahoo bgcolor=#f6f8f1 >
    <table width=100% bgcolor=#f6f8f1 border=0 cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0>
    <tr>
    <td>
    <table class=content  align=center  cellpadding=0  cellspacing=0  border=0 >
    <tr>
    <td>

    ID: ".$id." <br>

    Clients group name: ".$sitegroupname." <br>

    Managers Name: ".$manager." <br>

    Managers Email: ".$useremail." <br>

    Please log into your account as you have feedback notifications
    <br>

    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </body>
    </html>";

    echo $success = $mail->Send(); //Send the email.
}
```

Also cleaned up some of the PHP to simplify the entire thing.
NOTE: I excluded the email class as it isn't relevant to this problem.

EDIT:

TS informed me that the mail part wasn't working, so try using the default php mailer:

```
<?php 
include ("../dbconnect.php");

$sql='SELECT c.endofmonthform, c.startofmonthform, c.email, c.id, c.formlevel, c.mastersite, c.opmanager, u.userEmail FROM `clients` as c LEFT JOIN `users` as u on c.opmanager = u.userName WHERE endofmonthform="22/09/2016"'; //TODAYS DATE BACK HERE!

$result=mysql_query($sql); 

 while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){  

    $enddate = $row['endofmonthform']; // End

    $startdate = $row['startofmonthform']; // Start

    $email = $row['email']; //Email to send email to

    $id = $row['id'];

    $formlevel = $row['formlevel']; //To update and check formlevel

    $sitegroupname = $row['mastersite'];

    $manager = $row['opmanager'];

    $opemail = $row['userEmail'];

    mail($opemail, "subject", "message", "from");
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! Really appreciated

Comment: No problem, glad I could be of service :)